# What are the multiplicative inverses for K(n)?

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory

$$K(n) =\{x \in \mathbb R: \exists a,b \in \mathbb Q: x = a + b\sqrt n\}$$

With $n \in \mathbb N$, what are the multiplicative inverses $x^{-1}$ for K(n)?

Any advice regarding formatting is greatly appreciated as well since I'm new to all of this.

Comment: The standard notation for this set is $\mathbb Q(\sqrt n)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hint

$$
\frac{1}{a+b\sqrt{n}} = \frac{a-b\sqrt{n}}{a^2 - b^2 n}=*+*\sqrt{n}
$$

Comment: You need some hypothesis on $n$ to avoid a zero denominator.